# Choose between = or :=

Tags: excel, vba

I've just started with VBA programming in Excel. One thing drew my attention when I saw some sentences were written with `:=` and others with just an `=` .

Examples:

```
Sub Change_Page_Name()
    Worksheets(1).Name = "Prueba"
End Sub
```

```
Sub Add_Page()
    Worksheets.Add After:=Worksheets("Hoja2")
End Sub
```

I made these two examples, but I'm confused because I don't know when I should use `=` or `:=`

Comment: The : is part of the `After:` It would be neater to add a space between the : and the =

Comment: [`=` equal sign sets a property, object, or variable in VBA and `:=` the colon equal sign sets a value of a parameter for a property or method.](https://www.excelcampus.com/library/vba-difference-equal-sign-colon-equal-sign/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`:=` is used with Named Parameter assignment.  In your example `After` is a parameter name for the `.Add` Method of the `Worksheets` object.

`=` is used for both assignment and comparison.  In `Worksheets(1).Name = "Prueba"` you are assigning a value to the `Worksheets(1)` object `Name` parameter.

`=` would also be used to test a Parameter value,  eg `If  Worksheets(1).Name = "Prueba" Then`